# SAS libname json with arrays

Tags: sas

We are having a problem with the libname json, basically our dataset carries over the wrong field on object hierarchies.

here is a simple program:

```
filename resp "dataset.json";
filename pmap "map.json";
run;

libname example JSON fileref=resp map=pmap;
 proc datasets lib=example;
run;

data objects;
 set example.objects;
run;
```

the json dataset "dataset.json" looks like this:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "field": "wrong_answer"
    },
    {
      "objectHierarchy": [
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo2"
        },
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo1"
        },
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo"
        }
      ],
      "field": "right_answer"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the map "map.json" looks like this:

```
{
  "DATASETS": [
    {
      "DSNAME": "objects",
      "TABLEPATH": "/root/objects/objectHierarchy",
      "VARIABLES": [
        {
          "NAME": "map_to_this_level",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/objects/objectHierarchy/map_to_this_level",
          "CURRENT_LENGTH": 10
        },{
          "NAME": "field1",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/objects/field",
          "CURRENT_LENGTH": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the resulting dataset "example.objects" looks like this:

```
map_to_this_level      field
demo2                  wrong_answer
demo1
demo                   right_answer
```

My question is why does the wrong_answer value from the field on the first object with an empty objectHierarchy get mapped onto the row of data from the next object with actual values for it's objectHierarchy field?

the data should look like this:

```
map_to_this_level      field
demo2                  right_answer
demo1
demo                   right_answer
```

Comment: maybe some wired sas logic i thing demo2 is mapped on wrong_answer then everything is cleared. Now he reads only demo1 and no field before meeting map_to_this_level again so he output nothings. After clearing everything again he read demo and right_answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume a *human* expectation of:

```
field1        map_to_this_level
------------  -----------------
wrong_answer  <missing>
right_answer  demo2
right_answer  demo1
right_answer  demo
```

The `JSON` library engine is a **serial** decoder.  The order of the properties in the json being parsed do not mate well with the map specified and the operation of the internal map interpreter (i.e. the SAS JSON library engine black box)

Consider this example with these small changes:

- in **json** the `field` comes before `objectHierarchy`
- in **json** `wrong_answer` has an empty array `objectHierarchy`.  *Note: if the `objectHierarchy` was not present, no row would be output for `wrong_answer`*
- in **map** the `field1` value is retained using SAS JSON map feature `DATASETS/VARIABLES/OPTIONS:["RETAIN"]`

```
filename response catalog "work.json.sandbox.source";

data _null_;
  file response; input; put _infile_;
  datalines4;
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "field": "wrong_answer"
      ,
      "objectHierarchy": []
    },
    {
      "field": "right_answer"
      ,
      "objectHierarchy": [
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo2"
        },
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo1"
        },
        {
          "map_to_this_level": "demo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
;;;;
run;

filename pmap catalog "work.json.pmap.source";

data _null_;
  file pmap; input; put _infile_;
  datalines4;
{
  "DATASETS": [
    {
      "DSNAME": "objects",
      "TABLEPATH": "/root/objects/objectHierarchy",
      "VARIABLES": [
        {
          "NAME": "map_to_this_level",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/objects/objectHierarchy/map_to_this_level",
          "CURRENT_LENGTH": 10
        },
        {
          "NAME": "field1",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/objects/field",
          "CURRENT_LENGTH": 12

,  "OPTIONS": ["RETAIN"]

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
;;;;
run;

libname example JSON fileref=response map=pmap;

ods listing; options nocenter nodate nonumber formdlim='-'; title;

dm 'clear output';

proc datasets lib=example;
run;

proc print data=example.alldata;
run;

proc print data=example.objects;
run;

dm 'output';
```

Output

```
        map_to_
         this_
 Obs     level        field1

   1               wrong_answer
   2     demo2     right_answer
   3     demo1     right_answer
   4     demo      right_answer
```

If your json can not be trusted to be aligned with the mappings processed by SAS JSON library engine you will have to either:

- work the the json provider, or
- find an alternative interpreting mediary (Python, C#, etc) that can output modified json or an alternate interpreted form such as csv, that can be consumed by SAS.